# Check if a sequence exist in in collect in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Can somebody please tell how we can compare a sequence is present in the collection or not in Cypher / Neo4j?

Like if I say that while `collect()` is collecting the elements on traversal , can we check that this sequence is present when it has done collection `[Element1, Element2, Element3]`?

Comment: Rather than looking for sequences in a collection, it sounds like you're looking for sequences of labels on nodes in a path. If that's so, please clarify your question, as that opens up some more options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending if you allow gaps, you could either find the index of e1..e3 and see that they are ascending (with gaps) (apoc.coll.indexOf)

Or you could extract-3-element sublists and compare them.

```
WITH [1,2,3,4,5] as coll, [2,3,4] as seq
WHERE any(idx IN range(0,length(coll)-length(seq)) WHERE coll[idx..idx+length(seq)] = seq)
RETURN coll, seq
```

Comment: Thanks Michael . But this query is not returning me anything                        Match(le:Lead{name:'Varun1'})-[:have]->(e:Events)-[l:nextevent*]-(c) with le, collect(labels(c)) as row1, ["Email","SMS","Call"] as row2
where any(idx in range(0,length(row1) - length(row2)) where row1[idx..idx+length(row2)] = row2 ) return le

Comment: @VarunTahin The problem is that the `labels` function returns an array. Try this: `... collect(labels(c)[0]) as row1 ...`

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael .